# Access an array in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

lets imagine this scenario:

Game.h:

```
@interface Game : CCLayer
{    
    NSMutableArray* questions;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray* questions;


- (void) didLoadFromCCB;
- (void) pressitem:(id)sender;

@end
```

Game.m

```
 @implementation Game

 @synthesize questions;

 - (void) didLoadFromCCB
 {
     NSMutableArray *questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:-1],nil];

     NSLog(@"didload %@", questions);
 }


 - (void) pressitem:(id)sender
 {
     NSLog(@"pressitem %@",questions);
 }
@end
```

I get the log from didLoadFromCCB but on the pressitem it returns null. Shouldn't the array be accessible through all my implementation?

I know this seams like a really noob question, but i come from an actionscript/php background, and i just ordered a C and an Objective C book, but while i wait i just wanted to dig in a little.

thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope. `NSMutableArray *questions` declares a variable local to the `- didLoadFromCCB` method. It doesn't set the instance variable (a variable with a smaller scope suppresses a variable with the same name but a wider scope). Simply write

```
self.questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:-1]];
```

instead.

Comment: If you aren't using ARC, this will probably cause a memory leak, the property increases the retain count +1 as well as the alloc instruction. So you end with an object with a Retain Count of 2 and that you'll probably only release one in the dealloc method.

Comment: @PaulN I know. (You honestly thought I didn't know that?) But apart from me, nobody seems to be using MRC any more. Too bad.

Comment: thank you both =) indeed the self.questions worked, when i click it does log the array, but it crashes my app right after that, do i need some kind of dealoc after using it?

Comment: @RicardoCerqueira No, you rather need an hour to read an enhearten basic Objective-C and Apple's memory management guide.

Comment: No, I imagined that you will know this for your 54.2k reputation but added the comment for other people like you and me that are still using MRC and that may reach this answer and copy your code. ;)

Comment: I managed to fixe it doing     [questions autorelease]; when i create it. is this a good way to do it?

Comment: @RicardoCerqueira Omitting a call to release doesn't make your program crash. If adding a release fixed it, there's something very nasty going on. (Thanks for the accept, by the way.)

Comment: @H2CO3 really? cause it started working all of the sudden :| i just went to test again and took the autorelease off and it still works, deleated the app just in case and its working the way it wasnt when i asked.. weird stuff :X but just in case.. that didnt fixed my memory leak issue?

Comment: oh.. now that i think of it.. you where saying about the memory leaks because i have no dealloc method? cause i do have it, i just "striped" my code in order to be easier to understand my question :X

Answer (score 2):

Your local declaration of `questions` in `didLoadFromCCB` shadows the instance variable.  You should probably just make that line:

```
self.questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:-1],nil];
```

Then you will be creating the array and storing a pointer to it in the instance variable, rather than just making a local pointer that immediately goes out of scope.

Comment: Why not set the property, if it's declared?

Comment: That works too.  It's probably preferred, even.  I'll edit that in.

Comment: I think it should be noted that the memory management here is only correct under ARC. If you're using retain/release, this will immortalize the array.

Comment: @H2CO3 Perhaps a stupid question, but since I'm quite a newbie compared to you two I'll ask it anyways. If he does self.questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]...] doesn't this mean that the retain count will be 2 since he will access the property and not the iVar?

Comment: @Filip See Chuck's explanation.

Comment: @Chuck I completely lost the hope in iOS programmers, as such I don't anymore assume that one uses MRC.

Comment: @H2CO3 I can't see any good reason for anyone new to the platform to not use ARC, to be honest...but this discussion is probably best had somewhere else!

Comment: @lxt Good reasons not to begin with ARC: anyone new to the platform will 1. get lost with all the `__bridge_transfer_nonretaining_autoreleasing_weak_strong_semi-strong` casts, and 2. he will also not learn managing memory manually, which is an **obligatory** piece of knowledge, especially on embedded.

Comment: if you use a property i think it is preferable to avoid declaring the ivar as well. for the synthesize i suggest using Apple guideline and use _ivar (@synthesize questions=_questions or if you have xcode 4.5 > you can omit the synthesize). another small thing instead of [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-1] it is preferable using the new literal syntax @-1 (i cannot check now if with negative numbers work without parenthesis)

Comment: @H2CO3 - it used to be obligatory on desktop as well, but things change. Let's agree to disagree!